# Which Engine Control Module (ECM) Software version do I need to fix the Emissions Service Action 24DR for 2014 Volkswagen Passat?

Tags: vw, electronic-control-module, software, recall

Which Engine Control Module (ECM) Software version do I need to fix the Emissions Service Action 24DR issue for 2014 Volkswagen Passat?

---

Some details below:

The Emissions Service Action 24DR issue:

> Current Engine Control Module (ECM) software may cause unintended system faults. If present, these faults could lead to illumination of the malfunction indicator light (MIL). If the MIL is on, the vehicle will not pass an emissions inspection.

Full recall letter:

[image]

[image]

When I go on https://www.vw.com/owners-recalls/ and enter my car's VIN, it doesn't specify the ECM version that fixes the 24DR issue:

> ECU Update. VW ACTION CODE: 24DR
>
> START DATE: 09-14-2018
>
> DESCRIPTION: Current Engine Control Module (ECM) software may cause unintended system faults. If present, these faults could lead to illumination of the malfunction indicator light (MIL). If the MIL is on, the vehicle will not pass an emissions inspection.
>
> REMEDY: Update the ECM software.

[image]

Comment: I suggest you take the car to a dealer and they will check with equipment that has the latest info and be able to correctly identify what is the current spec of the car and tell you or update accordingly. At the moment you don’t seem to have the current spec of the vehicle or the capability of determining that.